# Dart Stream's listen() not calling onDone

Tags: dart, dart-io

I have a stream with a transformer that fuses the `UTF8.decoder` to the `LineSplitter`.  It works great but never calls the function specified in the `onDone` parameter.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

void main(List<String> arguments) {

  Stream<List<int>> stream = new File("input.txt").openRead();

  stream.transform(UTF8.decoder.fuse(const LineSplitter()))
      .listen((line) {
        stdout.writeln(line);            
      }, onDone: () {
          stdout.write("done");
      }).asFuture().catchError((_) => print(_));
}
```

Any ideas why it is never getting called?

Comment: I can reproduce but can't explain.

Comment: I'll wait a day and see if anyone has any ideas then submit a bug/feature request.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauerCheck out mezoni's answer.

Comment: asFuture () - This method overwrites the existing onDone and onError callbacks with new ones that complete the returned future.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamSubscription/asFuture.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you used the `asFuture()` method.

If you don't use that, `onDone` will be called properly when EOF is reached; otherwise, you should put a `.then((_) => print('done'))` after the `Future` return value of `asFuture()` for the same effect.

The resulting code should look like this:

```
(stream
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .transform(LineSplitter())
    .listen((line) => print(line))
    .asFuture())
        .then((_) => print("done"))
        .catchError((err) => stderr.writeln(err));
```